# zsh completion: use paths from specific dir, not the current one

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I have a custom function and zsh gives me default tab completion for it.
It completes paths from current working directory. That's great, but I'd
like the completion (*only* for this particular function) to behave a
little bit differently: as if I was always in a specific directory.

Can this be achieved with very little work? I'd love something like
`compdef myfunc="cd /my/dir"`...

To add some context, my function looks like this:

```
play() {
    (
        cd ~/Music/mp3 &&
        do-sth $1 &&
        open -a itunes $1
    )
}
```

and I would like to be able to do things like:

```
$ ls ~/Music/mp3
Slayer
$ cd ~
$ play S<tab>  # expands to "Slayer"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar solution for switching directories to my code projects.
Something like this might do the trick for you:

```
play() { open -a itunes ~/Music/mp3/$@; }
compctl -/ -W ~/Music/mp3 play
```